# Application.exe to open as runas administrator

Tags: c#

Hey i am trying to launch my Application.exe as a runas administrator but still not able to launch i have tried both verb="runas" as well as created app.manifest file but my exe not opening in administrator mode.

**I am using this code :**

```
                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = GetASDeploymentExe(),
                        Arguments = GetASDeploymentCmdArgs(),
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        Domain = "***",
                        UserName = username,
                        Password = secstr,
                        Verb = "runas"
                    }
                };

                proc.Start();
                config.ASDeploymentToolPID = proc.Id;

                string line = string.Empty;
                do
                {
                    line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                } while (!proc.HasExited);

                string error = string.Empty;
                while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
                {
                    error = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
                    Logger.WriteError(error);
                }
            }
```

Comment: How do you know that your "_…exe not opening in administrator mode…_"?

Comment: I have a terrible feeling that this is not going to end well. *why* is this question tagged [tag:asp.net]? You are aware that any C# code you write in asp.net runs on the server, and not on the machine with the browser, aren't you?

Comment: Uwe - So on the basis of i am executing some scripts and it is saying Please run the script with administrative privileges

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
//Vista or higher check
if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
   p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
}
```

Alternatively, [go the manifest route for your application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)

Comment: This code is not connected to OPs code (other variable names and comncept of assigning StartInfo). Additionally this bit is already included in OPs attempt